# Customizable DST Rules

Tags: php, coding-style, timezone, dst

**What's the task?**
By project specification i need to calculate DST rules for specific time zone offsets. Rules **cannot** be applied via standard instruments like `date_default_timezone_set()` because we can't rely on software configuration and can't get it updated if some DST rules will be changed.

**What i have?**
In situations when DST switch date is on the last week and the switch day of the last week is on the next month i need to decrement the number of the last week. For now i have only one **ugly** solution:

```
 $week = 5;
 if (
     (1 + 7 * ($week - 1)) 
     + $start['day_of_week'] 
     - date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $start['month'], 1, date('Y', $start['timestamp']))) 
     > 
     date('t', $start['month'])) 
 {
     $week--;
 }
```

**What am i looking for?**
I'm looking for any ideas for a simplest solution for this, or links =)

Comment: Interesting question. And no wonder it's coming from a Russian engineer, with all the recent confusion :) Would customizing the built-in time zone list / offsets list be an option? The one the date functions use? I have no idea what format they are stored in and whether they are accessible without recompiling PHP but it might be worth looking at

Comment: AFAIK it is system/library dependent and it can't be accessed via PHP. But i'll look at it =)

Comment: Yeah, at a quick glance, it looks like it's pretty deeply built in the system. You can [read the transitions in DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) but no writing

Comment: That why we are trying to calculate it from own resources.

Comment: Yeah. What server platform are you on? In case someone comes up with a solution outside PHP.

Comment: It will be a linux server. Unfortunately i don't know type of distro.

Comment: Do you need to calculate _the DST rules_, or do you need to calculate _timezone offset with DST rules already applied_?

Comment: I need to calculate timezone offset with applied custom DST rules. To do this i need to calculate time when i need to apply the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the system-wide timezone database and maintain custom updates to it.

[Official TZ database repository at IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)

It is available as source files that you can modify when needed and recompile into binary files that can be used by the `glibc` time functions, and consequently by all programs that use those time functions. You might need to find a way to disable any automatic updates to that database, if your distro performs such updates, or you will lose your custom changes.

I'm not certain if PHP actually follows the system-wide TZ database. The PECL `timezonedb` package seems to indicate that it is a separate recompiled version of the IANA database, so it might *not* observe changes in the system-wide database.

If PHP disregards changes in the system-wide database, you could retrieve the zone offset by invoking any external program that uses the `glibc` timezone-aware time functions and that supports returning the timezone offset, e.g.:

```
putenv('TZ=America/New_York');
$offset = exec('date +%z');
```

`$offset` will be in format `±HHMM`, so some additional parsing will be required.

You can also find the correct offset for specific timestamps, different from the current time:

```
$unix_timestamp = 1350757594;
$offset = exec('date +%z --date=@'.$unix_timestamp);
```

Of course, proper filtering through `escapeshellarg` would be required if the timestamp comes from an untrusted source.

**UPDATE: Here's a solution for a single DST ruleset; no external resources are used**

```
function calculate_offset($ts) {
    static $standard_offset = 2;    // = +2:00
    static $dst_offset      = 3;    // = +3:00
    static $dst_start       = 'last Sunday of March %d 1:00';
    static $dst_end         = 'last Sunday of October %d 1:00';

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $y = idate('Y', $ts);
    $start = strtotime(sprintf($dst_start, $y));
    $end = strtotime(sprintf($dst_end, $y));

    if ($start < $end) {
        // Northern hemisphere, DST starts earlier in the year than it ends
        $offset = ($ts >= $start && $ts < $end)? $dst_offset: $standard_offset;
    } else {
        // Southern hemisphere, DST ends earlier in the year than it starts
        $offset = ($ts >= $end && $ts < $start)? $standard_offset: $dst_offset;
    }
    $utc_time = strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', $ts);
    $local_time = strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', $ts + $offset * 60 * 60);
    printf("TS: %d; Offset: +%02d:00; UTC: %s; Local: %s\n", $ts, $offset, $utc_time, $local_time);
}
```

The example code uses the standard European DST rules and Eastern European Time offsets. You will need to find a way to express your DST start and end rules in the format understood by [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). A `%d` in your DST start/end rule will be replaced by the year your timestamp falls in, so that weekday-in-month rules will find correct dates for the specific year. All calculations are done in UTC times, so your rules should refer to DST start/end times in UTC.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try and let you know.

Comment: It's good solution, but i'm looking for something that can works without **any** system changes. Imagine that we have server in outer space without ssh access, but with remote DB =)